# React: Searches do not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I am attempting to implement my own search bar that also displays its search results.

What this should do is wait for a second after the users stop typing, search for what the user input, and then display the results as a list. Instead, the results are never rendered, until I wait for a full second and then start changing what the current input is. On top of all that after those results do appear they disappear after a second when they should stay on the screen until the search input is changed again. Can someone please give some guidance on how to go about fixing this?

This is what I have so far:

```
function Search() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [trackResults, setTrackResults] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSearch(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      let tracks = searchTracks();
      setTrackResults(tracks);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [search]);

  const searchTracks = () => {
    const results = [];
    if (search) {
      spotifyApi.searchTracks(search, { limit: 10 }).then((data) => {
        data.tracks.items.map((t) => {
          results.push({
            name: t.name,
            artist: t.artists.map((a) => a.name),
            id: t.id,
          });
        });
      });
      return results;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="Search">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="search for a  song"
        value={search}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>

      <ul>
        <Result results={trackResults} />
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

class Result extends Component {
  render() {
    return (this.props.results || []).map((result, i) => {
      return <li key={i}>{result.name}</li>;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `Result` component. actually in your `useEffect` you are calling `searchTracks` and this calls spotify api, which is definitly going to be asynchronous.
So you are getting undefined in your `useEffect` because you are not using `await` or anything like that.
So I sugggest you to modify your code like this-

```
const searchTracks = () => {
    const results = [];
    if (search) {
      spotifyApi.searchTracks(search, { limit: 10 }).then((data) => {
        data.tracks.items.map((t) => {
          results.push({
            name: t.name,
            artist: t.artists.map((a) => a.name),
            id: t.id,
          });
        });
      });
      setTrackResults(results); //instead of returning you can set here 
    }
  };
```

Instead of returning, you can set tracks inside then so you will get updated tracks and not `undefined`.
and change `useEffect` to this -

```
useEffect(() => {
     searchTracks();
  }, [search]);
```

This happens primarily because your `searchTracks` will not wait until `API` returns the result.  In this case, it will make a call to API and returns to `caller` with undefined or none in your case it's 'useEffect' and when `API` returns the result then depending on the status it will execute `then` block or `catch' block.

Comment: The reason why the OP had included the delay was that the event was not firing. I think you remove the timeout from your answer.

Comment: @HarshaVenkatram yes thanks. I have updated the answer.